# How to float a modal window in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using the jquery UI to create a floating window. I am able to create window. But I am having trouble in making it floating. I want that the window should be in top right corner of the "body". (now you can see its on right but at bottom) and I also want to make it moving. When I will scroll the page the window should also scroll along with it. e.g. http://manos.malihu.gr/tuts/jquery-floating-menu.html

Here is the code what I have done so far.

Please find the code on http://jsfiddle.net/z8rW6/1/

**Javascript Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){


$("#dialog").dialog();


var $parent = $('#body');
var windowHeight = $(window).height();
var parentAbsoluteTop = $parent.offset().top;
var parentAbsoluteBottom = parentAbsoluteTop + $parent.height();
var topStop = parentAbsoluteTop + $( ".selector" ).dialog( "option", "height" );
$('#dialog').dialog({ width: 300,height: 600 }).dialog('widget').position({
       my: 'right top',
       at: 'right top',
       of: $('#body')
    });

$(window).scroll(function(event) {
    var windowBottom = $(window).scrollTop() + windowHeight;

if (windowBottom < topStop)

    $('.selector').dialog({ dialogClass: 'myPosition1' });
else if (windowBottom >= topStop && windowBottom <= parentAbsoluteBottom)
    $('.selector').dialog({ dialogClass: 'myPosition2' });
else
    $('.selector').dialog({ dialogClass: 'myPosition3' });

})
```

**CSS Code:**

```
#page{
    width:800px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.myPosition1 {
position: 'absolute',
            top: '0px',
            bottom: 'auto',
            Right: '0'

}
.myPosition2 {
           position: 'fixed',
            top: 'auto',
            bottom: 'auto',
            Right: '0'
        }
 .myPosition3 {
         position: 'absolute',
        top: 'auto',
        bottom: '0px',
        Right: '0'
        }
#header{
    border:1px solid blue;
    height:15px;
    margin:8px;
}
#body{
    border:1px solid blue;
    height:5600px;
    margin:8px;
    position: relative;
}
#footer{
    border:1px solid blue;
    height:15px;
    margin:8px;
}
h1,h2{
    padding:16px;
}

#debug {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    color: red;
}
```

**Html Code:**

```
<html>
<head>
<LINK href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src='javascript/behaviour.js'></script>

</head>
<body style="font-size:62.5%;">
<div id="page">
 <div id="header"><h1>header</h1></div> 
    <div id="body" >
        <h1>content top -> when scrolling up the box should STOP here (at the line right above this text)</h1>
        <div id="dialog" title="Detailed FeedBack">I'm in a dialog </div>

        <span style="position: absolute; bottom: 0; ">content bottom -> when scrolling down the box should STOP here (at the line right below this text)</span>

    </div>
    <div id="footer"><h1>footer</h1></div>
    <div id="debug"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I created a jsFiddle for you - http://jsfiddle.net/z8rW6/.  Your example has a syntax error.  $box is not defined.

Comment: Thanks, Actually instead of box it should be height of dialog window

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work with your HTML, though you should increase `#footer`'s height (like to 400px) in your CSS to be able to confirm that it works :

```
var $d;
$(document).ready(function(){    
    var dlg_width = 300;
    var dlg_height = 200;
    var dlg_offset_x = $("#page").width() - dlg_width + 100;
    var dlg_margin_top = $("#header").outerHeight(true); // includeMargins=true
    var dlg_margin_bottom = $("#footer").outerHeight(true); // includeMargins=true

    $d = $('#dialog').dialog({
        width: dlg_width,
        height: dlg_height,
        position: [dlg_offset_x, dlg_margin_top]
    });

    $(window).bind('scroll', function(evt){
        var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        var bottom = $(document).height() - scrollTop;
            $d.dialog("option", {"position": [
                dlg_offset_x,
                ((dlg_margin_top - scrollTop > 0) ?
                    dlg_margin_top - scrollTop :
                        ((bottom - dlg_height > dlg_margin_bottom) ?
                            0 :
                            bottom - dlg_height - dlg_margin_bottom
                        )
                )
            ]});
    });
});
```

​
You can see it live here : http://jsfiddle.net/5TFQy/10/

Note that there are some quircks though:

- dialog sticks to the right of the viewport, when it should stick to the right of the `#body`. Did I miss something, or is it a limitation of `dialog()`?
- `dlg_margin_bottom = $("#footer").outerHeight(true)` isn't enough of a value to pixel-perfectly honour  your bottom-blue-line requirement. `#body`'s margin and border sizes should certainly be added. Tried to keep it <del>simple</del> not to complicated.

Comment: Last but not least: adding some easing function would make the dialog move look smoother.

Answer (score 5):

:) All of these answers are great ways to handle the question you technically asked... how to do it with jQuery. However - it is far easier to do it with very simple CSS.

Example:

```
<head>
 <style type="text/css">
     .myDialog {
         padding: 5px 10px;
         background: yellow;
         border: 1px solid #999;

         position: fixed;  /* This is the magic - stays during scroll. */
         top: 0; right: 0; /* These coordinates are now in 
                              relation to the first parent
                              with non-static positioning (body) */
     }
     .hidden {
         display: none;
     }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <!-- The rest of your page -->

 <!-- Put your dialog at the end of the body (or the beginning) 
      This way you don't have to worry about it getting hung up 
      within the positioning boxes of any other elements -->

 <div class="myDialog hidden">
  This is my dialog content!
 </div>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    // Now you can just toggle on and off the "hidden"
    // class to make the dialog hide/show.

    $('#SomeButton').bind('click', function (ev) {
        $('.myDialog').toggleClass('hidden');
    });
</script>
```

The exact same principles can be applied to your Modal dialog to make it move with the scrolling of the page, and that sort of thing.

For a working example of the above, take a look at this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WSZXL/

Answer (score 2):

I hope this will help you:

http://jsfiddle.net/lytican/UxZKH/2/

Comment: Dialog floats above the whole document, including above header and footer. See my answer for a solution that floats within the body area only, excluding header and footer as required.